# d3 - data - how to iterate over nested objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am trying to adapt the example in

- http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/62cf60e116ae821c06602793d265eaf6

to use a different data format as in ***accidents.js***.

so instead of having

```
var accidents = [
  {day:2,hour:1,count:127},{day:4,hour:1,count:141},{day:1,hour:1,count:134},{day:5,hour:1,count:174},
  {day:3,hour:1,count:131},{day:6,hour:1,count:333},{day:7,hour:1,count:311},{day:2,hour:2,count:79},
  {day:4,hour:2,count:99},{day:1,hour:2,count:117},{day:5,hour:2,count:123},{day:3,hour:2,count:92},
  {day:6,hour:2,count:257},{day:7,hour:2,count:293},{day:2,hour:3,count:55},{day:4,hour:3,count:73},
  .
  .
  .
];
```

I would like to use

```
var accidents_obj = {
  'Mon': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  'Tue': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  .
  .
  .
};
```

but I'm unable to adapt the part of the code in which `.attr("x"` and `.attr("y"` are calculated to work with my data object:

```
var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
  .data(accidents)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return (d.day - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("class", "hour bordered")
  .attr("width", gridSize)
  .attr("height", gridSize)
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.count);
  });
```

how do I have to iterate over `accidents_obj` to set `.attr("x"` and `.attr("y"` correctly?

---

full code in the hidden snippet below

```js
/* accidents.js */
var accidents = [{
  day: 2,
  hour: 1,
  count: 127
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 1,
  count: 141
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 1,
  count: 134
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 1,
  count: 174
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 1,
  count: 131
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 1,
  count: 333
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 1,
  count: 311
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 2,
  count: 79
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 2,
  count: 99
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 2,
  count: 117
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 2,
  count: 123
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 2,
  count: 92
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 2,
  count: 257
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 2,
  count: 293
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 3,
  count: 55
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 3,
  count: 73
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 3,
  count: 107
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 3,
  count: 89
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 3,
  count: 66
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 3,
  count: 185
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 3,
  count: 262
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 4,
  count: 39
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 4,
  count: 67
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 4,
  count: 59
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 4,
  count: 83
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 4,
  count: 45
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 4,
  count: 180
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 4,
  count: 220
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 5,
  count: 48
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 5,
  count: 57
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 5,
  count: 73
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 5,
  count: 76
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 5,
  count: 72
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 5,
  count: 168
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 5,
  count: 199
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 6,
  count: 129
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 6,
  count: 102
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 6,
  count: 129
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 6,
  count: 140
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 6,
  count: 117
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 6,
  count: 148
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 6,
  count: 193
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 7,
  count: 314
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 7,
  count: 284
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 7,
  count: 367
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 7,
  count: 270
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 7,
  count: 310
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 7,
  count: 179
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 7,
  count: 192
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 8,
  count: 806
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 8,
  count: 811
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 8,
  count: 850
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 8,
  count: 609
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 8,
  count: 846
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 8,
  count: 208
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 8,
  count: 144
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 9,
  count: 1209
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 9,
  count: 1214
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 9,
  count: 1205
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 9,
  count: 960
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 9,
  count: 1073
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 9,
  count: 286
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 9,
  count: 152
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 10,
  count: 750
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 10,
  count: 808
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 10,
  count: 610
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 10,
  count: 655
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 10,
  count: 684
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 10,
  count: 482
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 10,
  count: 253
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 11,
  count: 591
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 11,
  count: 593
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 11,
  count: 573
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 11,
  count: 695
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 11,
  count: 622
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 11,
  count: 676
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 11,
  count: 326
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 12,
  count: 653
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 12,
  count: 679
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 12,
  count: 639
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 12,
  count: 736
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 12,
  count: 687
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 12,
  count: 858
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 12,
  count: 402
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 13,
  count: 738
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 13,
  count: 749
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 13,
  count: 631
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 13,
  count: 908
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 13,
  count: 888
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 13,
  count: 880
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 13,
  count: 507
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 14,
  count: 792
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 14,
  count: 847
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 14,
  count: 752
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 14,
  count: 1033
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 14,
  count: 942
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 14,
  count: 983
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 14,
  count: 636
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 15,
  count: 906
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 15,
  count: 1031
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 15,
  count: 954
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 15,
  count: 1199
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 15,
  count: 1014
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 15,
  count: 1125
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 15,
  count: 712
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 16,
  count: 1101
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 16,
  count: 1158
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 16,
  count: 1029
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 16,
  count: 1364
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 16,
  count: 1068
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 16,
  count: 1062
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 16,
  count: 736
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 17,
  count: 1303
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 17,
  count: 1426
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 17,
  count: 1270
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 17,
  count: 1455
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 17,
  count: 1407
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 17,
  count: 883
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 17,
  count: 666
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 18,
  count: 1549
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 18,
  count: 1653
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 18,
  count: 1350
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 18,
  count: 1502
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 18,
  count: 1507
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 18,
  count: 830
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 18,
  count: 652
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 19,
  count: 998
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 19,
  count: 1070
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 19,
  count: 787
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 19,
  count: 1027
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 19,
  count: 1019
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 19,
  count: 575
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 19,
  count: 519
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 20,
  count: 661
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 20,
  count: 756
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 20,
  count: 596
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 20,
  count: 730
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 20,
  count: 648
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 20,
  count: 494
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 20,
  count: 486
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 21,
  count: 431
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 21,
  count: 539
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 21,
  count: 430
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 21,
  count: 509
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 21,
  count: 457
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 21,
  count: 443
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 21,
  count: 421
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 22,
  count: 352
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 22,
  count: 428
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 22,
  count: 362
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 22,
  count: 462
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 22,
  count: 390
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 22,
  count: 379
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 22,
  count: 324
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 23,
  count: 329
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 23,
  count: 381
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 23,
  count: 293
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 23,
  count: 393
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 23,
  count: 313
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 23,
  count: 374
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 23,
  count: 288
}, {
  day: 2,
  hour: 24,
  count: 211
}, {
  day: 4,
  hour: 24,
  count: 249
}, {
  day: 1,
  hour: 24,
  count: 204
}, {
  day: 5,
  hour: 24,
  count: 417
}, {
  day: 3,
  hour: 24,
  count: 211
}, {
  day: 6,
  hour: 24,
  count: 379
}, {
  day: 7,
  hour: 24,
  count: 203
}];


/* script.js */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// Set up and initiate svg containers ///////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

var days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
  times = d3.range(24);

var margin = {
  top: 170,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 70,
  left: 50
};

var width = Math.max(Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000), 500) - margin.left - margin.right - 20,
  gridSize = Math.floor(width / times.length),
  height = gridSize * (days.length + 2);

//SVG container
var svg = d3.select('#trafficAccidents')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Reset the overall font size
var newFontSize = width * 62.5 / 900;
d3.select("html").style("font-size", newFontSize + "%");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////// Draw Heatmap /////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Based on the heatmap example of: http://blockbuilder.org/milroc/7014412

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  }) / 2, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range(["#FFFFDD", "#3E9583", "#1F2D86"])
//.interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
  .data(days)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * gridSize;
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis");
  });

var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
  .data(times)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return ((i >= 8 && i <= 17) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis");
  });

var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
  .data(accidents)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return (d.day - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("class", "hour bordered")
  .attr("width", gridSize)
  .attr("height", gridSize)
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.count);
  });

//Append title to the top
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -90)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Number of Traffic accidents per Day & Hour combination");
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "subtitle")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -60)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("The Netherlands | 2014");

//Append credit at bottom
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "credit")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", gridSize * (days.length + 1) + 80)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Based on Miles McCrocklin's Heatmap block");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////// Create the gradient for the legend ///////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Extra scale since the color scale is interpolated
var countScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range([0, width])

//Calculate the variables for the temp gradient
var numStops = 10;
countRange = countScale.domain();
countRange[2] = countRange[1] - countRange[0];
countPoint = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numStops; i++) {
  countPoint.push(i * countRange[2] / (numStops - 1) + countRange[0]);
} //for i

//Create the gradient
svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "legend-traffic")
  .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%").attr("y2", "0%")
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(d3.range(numStops))
  .enter().append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d, i) {
    return countScale(countPoint[i]) / width;
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(d, i) {
    return colorScale(countPoint[i]);
  });

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////// Draw the legend ////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var legendWidth = Math.min(width * 0.8, 400);
//Color Legend container
var legendsvg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legendWrapper")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (gridSize * days.length + 40) + ")");

//Draw the Rectangle
legendsvg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "legendRect")
  .attr("x", -legendWidth / 2)
  .attr("y", 0)
  //.attr("rx", hexRadius*1.25/2)
  .attr("width", legendWidth)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", "url(#legend-traffic)");

//Append title
legendsvg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "legendTitle")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", -10)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Number of Accidents");

//Set scale for x-axis
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([-legendWidth / 2, legendWidth / 2])
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })]);

//Define x-axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(5)
  //.tickFormat(formatPercent)
  .scale(xScale);

//Set up X axis
legendsvg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (10) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  fill: #8C8C8C;
  text-align: center;
}

.timeLabel,
.dayLabel {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 300;
}

text.axis-workweek,
text.axis-worktime {
  fill: #404040;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  fill: #4F4F4F;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.credit {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.axis path,
.axis tick,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

text {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  fill: #4F4F4F;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="trafficAccidents"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange your data to the structure that is used in blocks which you mention this way:

```
function getAccidents(data) {
    var result = [];

  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(dayName, index) {
    Object.keys(data[dayName]).forEach(function(hour, index) {
      result.push({
        hour: hour,
        day: Object.keys(data).indexOf(dayName) + 1,
        count: data[dayName][hour]
      })
    });
  });

    return result;
}

var accidents = getAccidents(accidents_obj);
```

Look at the working example in hidden snippets below:

First of this data structure:

```
{
  'Mon': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  ...
}
```

```js
var accidents_obj = {
  'Mon': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  'Tue': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  'Wed': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  'Thu': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  'Fri': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  'Sat': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  'Sun': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},        
};

function getAccidents(data) {
 var result = [];
  
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(dayName, index) {
    Object.keys(data[dayName]).forEach(function(hour, index) {
      result.push({
        hour: hour,
        day: Object.keys(data).indexOf(dayName) + 1,
        count: data[dayName][hour]
      })
    });
  });
  
 return result;
}

var accidents = getAccidents(accidents_obj);

var labels = Object.keys(accidents_obj),
  times = d3.range(24);

var margin = {
  top: 170,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 70,
  left: 70
};

var width = Math.max(Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000), 500) - margin.left - margin.right - 20,
  gridSize = Math.floor(width / times.length),
  height = gridSize * (labels.length + 2);

//SVG container
var svg = d3.select('#trafficAccidents')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Reset the overall font size
var newFontSize = width * 62.5 / 900;
d3.select("html").style("font-size", newFontSize + "%");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////// Draw Heatmap /////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Based on the heatmap example of: http://blockbuilder.org/milroc/7014412

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  }) / 2, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range(["#FFFFDD", "#3E9583", "#1F2D86"])
//.interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
  .data(labels)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * gridSize;
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis");
  });

var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
  .data(times)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return ((i >= 8 && i <= 17) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis");
  });

var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
  .data(accidents)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return (d.day - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("class", "hour bordered")
  .attr("width", gridSize)
  .attr("height", gridSize)
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.count);
  });

//Append title to the top
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -90)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Number of Traffic accidents per Day & Hour combination");
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "subtitle")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -60)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("The Netherlands | 2014");

//Append credit at bottom
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "credit")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", gridSize * (labels.length + 1) + 80)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Based on Miles McCrocklin's Heatmap block");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////// Create the gradient for the legend ///////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Extra scale since the color scale is interpolated
var countScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range([0, width])

//Calculate the variables for the temp gradient
var numStops = 10;
countRange = countScale.domain();
countRange[2] = countRange[1] - countRange[0];
countPoint = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numStops; i++) {
  countPoint.push(i * countRange[2] / (numStops - 1) + countRange[0]);
} //for i

//Create the gradient
svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "legend-traffic")
  .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%").attr("y2", "0%")
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(d3.range(numStops))
  .enter().append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d, i) {
    return countScale(countPoint[i]) / width;
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(d, i) {
    return colorScale(countPoint[i]);
  });

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////// Draw the legend ////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var legendWidth = Math.min(width * 0.8, 400);
//Color Legend container
var legendsvg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legendWrapper")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (gridSize * labels.length + 40) + ")");

//Draw the Rectangle
legendsvg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "legendRect")
  .attr("x", -legendWidth / 2)
  .attr("y", 0)
  //.attr("rx", hexRadius*1.25/2)
  .attr("width", legendWidth)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", "url(#legend-traffic)");

//Append title
legendsvg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "legendTitle")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", -10)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Number of Accidents");

//Set scale for x-axis
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([-legendWidth / 2, legendWidth / 2])
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })]);

//Define x-axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(5)
  //.tickFormat(formatPercent)
  .scale(xScale);

//Set up X axis
legendsvg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (10) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  fill: #8C8C8C;
  text-align: center;
}

.timeLabel,
.dayLabel {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 300;
}

text.axis-workweek,
text.axis-worktime {
  fill: #404040;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  fill: #4F4F4F;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.credit {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.axis path,
.axis tick,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

text {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  fill: #4F4F4F;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="trafficAccidents"></div>
```

And second for that:

```
{
  '2017-11-10': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}
  ...
}
```

```js
var accidents_obj = {
  '2017-11-10': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  '2017-11-11': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  '2017-11-12': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  '2017-11-13': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  '2017-11-14': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  '2017-11-15': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  '2017-11-16': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-17': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},
  '2017-11-18': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-19': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-20': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-21': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-22': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-23': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-24': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-25': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-26': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-27': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-28': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-29': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-11-30': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-12-01': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-12-02': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-12-03': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-12-04': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-12-05': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-12-06': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0}, 
  '2017-12-07': {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 10, 13: 9, 14: 9, 15: 1, 16: 10, 17: 5, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 4, 21: 6, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 0},   
};

function getAccidents(data) {
 var result = [];
  
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(dayName, index) {
    Object.keys(data[dayName]).forEach(function(hour, index) {
      result.push({
        hour: hour,
        day: Object.keys(data).indexOf(dayName) + 1,
        count: data[dayName][hour]
      })
    });
  });
  
 return result;
}

var accidents = getAccidents(accidents_obj);

var labels = Object.keys(accidents_obj),
  times = d3.range(24);

var margin = {
  top: 170,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 70,
  left: 70
};

var width = Math.max(Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000), 500) - margin.left - margin.right - 20,
  gridSize = Math.floor(width / times.length),
  height = gridSize * (labels.length + 2);

//SVG container
var svg = d3.select('#trafficAccidents')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Reset the overall font size
var newFontSize = width * 62.5 / 900;
d3.select("html").style("font-size", newFontSize + "%");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////// Draw Heatmap /////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Based on the heatmap example of: http://blockbuilder.org/milroc/7014412

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  }) / 2, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range(["#FFFFDD", "#3E9583", "#1F2D86"])
//.interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
  .data(labels)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * gridSize;
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis");
  });

var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
  .data(times)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return ((i >= 8 && i <= 17) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis");
  });

var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
  .data(accidents)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return (d.day - 1) * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("class", "hour bordered")
  .attr("width", gridSize)
  .attr("height", gridSize)
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.count);
  });

//Append title to the top
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -90)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Number of Traffic accidents per Day & Hour combination");
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "subtitle")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", -60)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("The Netherlands | 2014");

//Append credit at bottom
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "credit")
  .attr("x", width / 2)
  .attr("y", gridSize * (labels.length + 1) + 80)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Based on Miles McCrocklin's Heatmap block");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////// Create the gradient for the legend ///////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Extra scale since the color scale is interpolated
var countScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })])
  .range([0, width])

//Calculate the variables for the temp gradient
var numStops = 10;
countRange = countScale.domain();
countRange[2] = countRange[1] - countRange[0];
countPoint = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numStops; i++) {
  countPoint.push(i * countRange[2] / (numStops - 1) + countRange[0]);
} //for i

//Create the gradient
svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "legend-traffic")
  .attr("x1", "0%").attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "100%").attr("y2", "0%")
  .selectAll("stop")
  .data(d3.range(numStops))
  .enter().append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d, i) {
    return countScale(countPoint[i]) / width;
  })
  .attr("stop-color", function(d, i) {
    return colorScale(countPoint[i]);
  });

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////// Draw the legend ////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var legendWidth = Math.min(width * 0.8, 400);
//Color Legend container
var legendsvg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legendWrapper")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (gridSize * labels.length + 40) + ")");

//Draw the Rectangle
legendsvg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "legendRect")
  .attr("x", -legendWidth / 2)
  .attr("y", 0)
  //.attr("rx", hexRadius*1.25/2)
  .attr("width", legendWidth)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", "url(#legend-traffic)");

//Append title
legendsvg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "legendTitle")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", -10)
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Number of Accidents");

//Set scale for x-axis
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([-legendWidth / 2, legendWidth / 2])
  .domain([0, d3.max(accidents, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })]);

//Define x-axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(5)
  //.tickFormat(formatPercent)
  .scale(xScale);

//Set up X axis
legendsvg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (10) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  fill: #8C8C8C;
  text-align: center;
}

.timeLabel,
.dayLabel {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 300;
}

text.axis-workweek,
text.axis-worktime {
  fill: #404040;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  fill: #4F4F4F;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.credit {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.axis path,
.axis tick,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

text {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  fill: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  fill: #4F4F4F;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="trafficAccidents"></div>
```

The code for this two examples the same, only different keys of the initial data object.

Comment: thank you mikhail. I did exatly this as a first step. then I realized that I would like to display the data for a whole month or even year (for a different use case)... so I have 31 rows or 365 rows... mapping that data to a week would not work...

Comment: @udo Do you have something like this - https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318 and this - http://bl.ocks.org/KathyZ/c2d4694c953419e0509b ?

Comment: the results should look exactly like in http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/62cf60e116ae821c06602793d265eaf6, just with 365 rows instead of the 7 for a week.
note: don't worry about the color scale. I would already be happy to be able to see those rectangles appear :)

Comment: How will your initial data look in that cases?

Comment: like `accidents_obj`, with 7 rows for a week, 31 for a month and 365 for a year.
note: for month and year objects, the key would contain the date (e.g.  "2017-11-14", "2017-11-15", etc.), instead of "Mon", "Tue", ...

Comment: smart move! you are the man! I definitely tried a more complicated approach instead of "just" transforming the data to the format the example was already handling "out of the box". thank you very much!